# Проблема передачи информации между сценами

Tags: c#, unity3d

Создал отдельный объект для передачи, к которому передаётся значение переменной из другого скрипта. Для нахождения скрипта из которого берётся переменная объект со скриптом крепится к скрипту передачи, но при переходе на другую сцену закреплённый объект слетает и выходит ошибка. Подскажите как пофиксить или не дать объекту слетать.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Почему бы не передавать информацию между сценами с помощью PlayerPrefs или статического класса / статической переменной?

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался.